# Find all common substrings with a minimum length of 2 characters

Tags: java, algorithm

Task's content:

Find all (starting from the longest, the shortest ending) common substrings with a minimum length of 2 characters, which do not overlap with previously found.

My task is to remake below code or write new one. I don't even know how to start with it :/

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text1 = "AABABB";
        String text2 = "BAABAB";

        int len1 = text1.length();
        int len2 = text2.length();

        int max = 0;
        int position_w1 = -1;
        int position_w2 = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < len1 - max; i++)
        {

            for (int k = len2 - 1; k >= 0; k--)
            {
                int counter = 0;
                int limit = Math.min(len2, (len1 -i + k) );  
                for (int j = k; j < limit; j++)
                {
                    if (text1.charAt(i+j-k) == text2.charAt(j)) 
                    {                        
                        counter++;

                        if (max < counter) 
                        {
                            max = counter;
                            position_w1 = i + j - k - max + 1;
                            position_w2 = j - max + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else counter = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Position of text1: " + position_w1 + ", position of text2: " + position_w2 + ", length: " + max);



        System.out.println(text1.substring(0, position_w1) + "\u001B[31m" 
                + text1.substring(position_w1, max + position_w1) + "\u001B[0m" + text1.substring(max + position_w1) );
        System.out.println(text2.substring(0, position_w2) + "\u001B[31m" 
                + text2.substring(position_w2, max + position_w2) + "\u001B[0m" + text2.substring(max + position_w2) );
    }
```

Comment: When asking about homework (1) Be aware of your school policy: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) Ask about a specific problem with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Comment: "Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  "I don't even know how to start" falls into this category.  StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this :

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    String text1 = "AABABB";
    String text2 = "BAABAB";

    int maxLen = 3;

    for (int len = 2; len < maxLen; len++) {
        ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>> intervalsText1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>> intervalsText2 = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < text1.length() - len; i++) { 
            String sub1 = text1.substring(i, i + len);

            for (int j = 0; j < text2.length() - len; i++) {
                String sub2 = text2.substring(j, j + len);

                if(sub1.equals(sub2)){
                    //check if overlapping
                    for(Pair<Integer, Integer> inter : intervalsText1){
                        for(Pair<Integer, Integer> inter : intervalsText1){
                            if(!isInsideInterval(inter, i) && !isInsideInterval(inter, i + len)){
                                if(!isInsideInterval(inter, j) && !isInsideInterval(inter, j + len)){ 
                                    //the strings are equal and outside previous strings
                                    intervalsText1.add(Pair.of(i, i + len));
                                    intervalsText2.add(Pair.of(j, j + len));
                                }
                            }   
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isInsideInterval(Pair<Integer, Integer> interval, int toCheck){
    if(interval.getLeft() < toCheck && interval.getRight() > toCheck)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

*Please note that I haven't checked it working

Comment: Unfortunally it goes into infinity :/

Comment: What goes to infinity ?

Comment: I have edited the overlapping method, it is a bit uglier but I think it should work

Answer (score 0):

As this is home work, just some mental help.

Immediately diving into for-i like loops is hard to read and/or change.

Consider how one would do the task oneself, and see what the original writer did.

Starting with the maximal subsequence, would be:

```
int max = Math.min(len1, len2);
...
--max;
```

or even

```
for (int max = Math.min(len1, len2); may > 0; --max) {
    for (int i = 0; i + max <= len1; ++i) {
         if (match found) {
             print match;
             i += max - 1;
         }
    }
}
```

The for-k loop does a --k; a bit needlessly IMHO.

Matching a substring and when matched skip by `i += max;` or `i += max - 1;` would benefit from the `String.substring` or your own function for that.

By the way, when ready try to consider things like skipping a second occurrence of a sought substring: "AB" appears twice in `text1`. Good names important, comments might help. Otherwise demerits for "circumstantial code" might follow.

```
         int notEarlierPos = text1.indexOf(text1.subtring(i, i + max));
         if (notEarlierPos == i) { // Not already treated earlier.
             int matchPos = text2.indexOf(text1.subtring(i, i + max));
             if (matchPos != -1) {
                 print match;
                 i += max - 1;
             }
         }
```